# RealmSwift. Difficulties initializing List after converting to Swift 4

Tags: swift, realm, swift4

I've got a task to convert an existing project to Swift4 (from Swift 2.3, don't ask O_o). Managed to fix almost everything except this issue using RealmSwift:

Old code:

```
class func myFunc() -> List<MyClass> {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    return List(realm.objects(MyClass).sorted("name", ascending: true))
}
```

Getting compiler error for the return statement:

```
Argument passed to call that takes no arguments
```

When I trying to fix like this, compiler is silent, but the function doesn't do its job:

```
return List<MyClass>()
```

So which is then the right way to initialize List with a collection of custom objects? Please, help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List` doesn't have an initializer accepting a `Results` instance in RealmSwift 3.1.0 (I'm not sure since when though). `List`'s only initializer doesn't take any input arguments and it creates an empty `List` instance.

You can work around this by creating an empty `List` using the only initializer, then calling `append` to add the elements of the `Results` collection to the list.

```
func myFunc() -> List<MyClass> {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let list = List<MyClass>()
    list.append(objectsIn: realm.objects(MyClass.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "name", ascending: true))
    return list
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've solved this by myself already, but your solution is better: shorter and more elegant. I used the 'for loop' with simple 'append'.

Comment: The `append` method's documentation says that you may only called it during a write transaction.

Comment: @JakubTruhlář that's only true for persisted `List` objects, but unlike `Results`, you can create a `List` instance, so if you don't want to persist the `List` in Realm right away, you can safely call `append` on it outside a write transaction